# How to apply (and change) classes to an SVG elements that already exist

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm very very new in programming and D3 and I have a basic problem (I think) but I couldn't found the solution.
I created groups of circles which all together represent a Chamber (legislative hall).
Now, I would like to change the color of the circles according to different datasets.
I tried to apply different classes or styles but I couldn't select the right numbers of circles.
Here is the code.

```
svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(grupos)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function (d,i) { return "translate(400,380) rotate(" + -1* (i * 5) + ")";})
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(circulos)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("cx", function (d,i) {return (i+3) * 20;})

    //change the size of circles gradually
    .attr("r", function (d,i) {return (Math.pow((i+1),1/3)*2);});
```

To view the project

http://jsfiddle.net/ploscri/JrRdc/

Could anyone help please?

Comment: What are you trying to select by?

Comment: if you want to different colors to circles just do this
**var colors = d3.scale.category10();
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return colors(i); })**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To color half of the circles blue:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return i < 190 ? 'blue' : 'red'; })
```

If you're just trying to show different vote totals, number of men v. women, or another proportion, just change the 190.

To change the color of the circles based on different datasets in a more complicated way: I would suggest combining the datasets together into an array of object where each entry represents a single legislator. Bind that data to your circles and you can change easily adjust the circle's size, position, and color based on the legislator's properties.